GORM SetupJoinTable. When to use
I'm trying to use customized join tables with GORM but everytime I need fetch data it says table does not exist even it existing. But when I use the method SetupJoinTable it woks fine. So do I really need to call SetupJoinTable every single time I create a gorm connection ?
This code does not work(Tables already created)
db, err := GetGorm()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var l Foo
    db = db.Model(&l).Joins("Bars").Find(&l)
    if db.Error != nil {
        panic(db.Error)
    }
    println("size of bars is", len(l.Bars))

but this code works fine:
    db, err := GetGorm()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _ = db.SetupJoinTable(&Foo{}, "Bars", &FooBar{})
    _ = db.SetupJoinTable(&Bar{}, "Foos", &FooBar{})

    var l Foo
    db = db.Model(&l).Joins("Bars").Find(&l)
    if db.Error != nil {
        panic(db.Error)
    }
    println("size of bars is", len(l.Bars))

So do I need to call it everytime ?
(I'm so sorry 'bout my english, I'm not native)
